# Drag marker in "repeated" map, wrong latlng

Tags: leaflet

When you render a map if you zoom out far enough it will repeat the map infinite times.

The problem is that the coordinates will increase if you drag something outside the "original" map.

Example:

[image]

and if you drag to the left

[image]

The 'lat' seems to be fine, since it only duplicates horizontally, but 'lng' is way off.

Is there a way to correct the position?

L.vesion = "1.0.0-rc.3+27f05a2"

Comment: lng isn't "way off", it's just a world over.  360 + 52 = 412.

Comment: Midavalo is right.  Try limiting your min zoom and using world wrap - that will keep the coordinates within 0-360

Answer (score 1):

A simple calculation with the maximum bounds of the globe's coordinates can do the trick.

Top left corner: (85, -180).
Bottom right corner: (-85.05115, 180).

Just have to verify if it's inside the borders.